# having trouble collapsing borders on a specific table only

Tags: css

```
table.perimeter td,
table.perimeter th 
{
border: 1px solid blue;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

I've tried a few things nothing works.
the borders around each cell stay separated. help!

Comment: The answers could not fit your needs since you didn't provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Or add a class to table like "table1"

```
.table1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Apologies, I'll be sure to ask questions with more clarity going forward; I am new.  I was missing the  "table.perimeter" tag ... thank you SO MUCH Cedric.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `border-collapse` to the table ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)).

```css
table.perimeter {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="perimeter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">The table header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>The table body</td>
      <td>with two columns</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Since we don't have your structure, I can't tell if `table.perimeter` is a sufficient selector to apply it to a specific table, you may have to add an `id`